# I need to dynamic wait solution in Karate Mobile Framework instead of delay()

Tags: mobile, karate

Although I use waitFor() in my UI test properly in the Karate framework, it does not work for mobile test. I think there is an issue with Appium or the emulator.I also tried with real devices but still no solution. How my test can wait until the URL is ready to accept HTTP connections by using the Karate framework?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is probably an area that needs work, do consider contributing code or helping others to do so

Comment: As of karate `1.0.1` `wait` functions are predominantly designed for web, it should support mobile apps as well

opened an issue here -> https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1548, please track this issue for more updates

Answer (score 1):

As of karate `1.0.1` wait functions are predominantly designed for the web. we've added the support for `waitFor` in mobile and it should be available in the next release,

- `waitFor(locator)`

It would be more helpful if you follow the instructions [Devloper Guide](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide) and confirm if this works.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. We are just carrying out with the thread.sleep but as you know that's not the right solution for the long term. I will be glad if the thread stays active and open to any contributions about the issue. And looking forward to the next release. Thanks!